# Spidey-sense in Jessica Jones?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, jessica-jones

In "AKA Playland", the final episode of Season 2, Jessica Jones tells Vido about her *heroic* incident and the conversation goes as such:

> **Vido:** Did you save anybody today? 
>  *Some conversation later...* 
> **Jessica:** ...And this guy came in and he was all jumpy and dope-sick. And I knew he was there to rob the place... 
> **Vido:** Because of your *spidey-sense*? 
> **Jessica:** I don't have *spidey-sense*...

Now this put me off by a bit since the Netflix shows are in MCU continuity and apparently occurs after Avengers. Thus we can assume that the current season could be around AoU times... So how does Vido know about **spidey-sense**? It's not like having a Captain America toy.

**Spidey-sense** is a feature exclusive to Spider-man and he doesn't go around saying it in the MCU and unless Vido reads "Spider-man" comics, this reference is off-putting within the MCU universe.

## TLDR: How does Vido know about *spidey-sense*?

Comment: Pretty good question, actually. Because even the timeline doesn't matter., Even if Spiderman is a known hero at this point, it still makes no sense for random people to know about the Spidey-Sense. That is something we know about because Spiderman is a character we read about from his first-person perspective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently Netflix has changed it to **super-sense** now... So they knew the mistake...

The spidey-sense line apparently existed for a day or so in Netflix before being changed... So yeah, this line must have made through before Marvel got the deal with Spider-man and thus Jessica Jones showrunners could just go with it as part of references...

Answer (score 2):

The current seasons of the Netflix shows typically take place in-universe just a few months before the air dates, so for *Jessica Jones* season two, that would be late summer/fall of 2017. The events of *Spider-Man: Homecoming* would certainly have taken place by then, in which Spider-Man did make the news. (In fact, it's not exactly clear where to place *Homecoming* in the timeline, but it's probably *earlier* than it's air date.)

More notably, the Netflix series all take place in New York City (Hells Kitchen, Harlem, etc.) This is also where Spider-Man lives and operates -- in the comics, Spider-Man and Daredevil team up fairly regularly, and share many of the same villains.

Therefore, it's not unreasonable to imagine that someone living in Hells Kitchen in 2017 would know about Spider-Man, or at least stories about Spider-Man, and that the term "spidey-sense" had entered common usage in that part of the country.

Comment: I personally don't think timeline even matters. There's no way a random person inside the MCU should know the name of the reflex that takes place inside Peter Parker's head.

Comment: @kutuluMike I think is problem is, where does Peter Parker make it public that he has spidey-sense. The question is related to the private nature of this gift, so how would she (or anyone) know what spidey-sense is unless 1) peter publicly telling people 2) she read the comics (not likely to be the same in her universe as IRL) 3) or she personally knew spider-man.

Comment: The thing is, in the current MCU: SPidey-sense is only hinted at Infinity War or so... And even then, Spidey-sense is not something Spider-man goes around saying. It's a thought in his ming and not told out-loud. So unless Vido got a Spider-man book from the future, this doesn't hold true...

Comment: __Spider-Man: Homecoming__ [didn't have Spidey-Sense](http://collider.com/spider-man-homecoming-spidey-sense-explained/).